# C++ COM Interop: Using C# namespace with dot notation in c++

Tags: c++, com, interop

I have a C# namespace defined as A.B.C which I tried using in a C++ header with

using namespace A::B::C;

and I get error C2653: A is not a class or namespace.

The unmanaged project is referencing the managed project with this namespace.  How do I get around this?  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM Interop doesn't let you do that.  COM interop lets you retrieve a C++ COM interface pointer to a .NET object, using e.g. `CoCreateInstance`.

If you want to refer to the C# namespaces and types directly (not through a COM interface pointer), you want C++/CLI (the `/clr` option for Visual C++).

Comment: Thanks.  I simplified things with a simple namespace without the dots and it seems to like that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Calling managed code from unmanaged code is kinda nasty.  You have to do tricky stuff to get a function pointer to the managed function.  See this example for how to do it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/unmanaged_to_managed.aspx

Answer (score 2):

COM does not have support for C# namespaces, so there's no way of doing what you want.  Sorry :(.

As Ben Voight mentioned, you can use C++/CLI if you want to preserve the C# namespaces.